# How to disable another button when sound clip is over in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing Android application for creating media player.I have run the application properly for playing the music on button click . When i click the button_Start the music is start to playing and click on the same button_Start for pause and resume/start.when the button_Start is click my button_Second is disable and when button_Start click for pause then button_Second is disable is properly . But I want when sound clip is over my button_Second is enable and button_Start is disabled .I'm getting error when i run the app (IllegelStateException) . I don't know how can i do this.Can any one help me.Thanks in advanced.

Here is my code .This is y Audio_Activity class.

```
public class Audio_Activity extends Activity
{
    private  MediaPlayer mp;
    Button btnStartStop ;
    Button btnChapter ;


    ImageView imgVw;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.audio);
        init();


        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.ennamo_yadho);
        Log.e("Song is playing","in  Mediya Player ");

        System.out.println("B4 button Click!!!!");


        System.out.println("After Button click !! ");
        if(mp!=null)
        {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            System.out.println("Media Player Is Stop and release");

            btnChapter.setEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("btnChapter is enabled when media player is 
                         release !!!");

        }

        btnStartStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    if(mp!=null)
                    {
                            mp.pause();
                        imgVw.setImageResource(R.raw.images1);
                        btnChapter.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    // Resume song
                    if(mp!=null)
                    {
                            mp.start();
                        imgVw.setImageResource(R.raw.teddy_two);
                        btnChapter.setEnabled(false);


                    }


            }}
        });



    }


    public void init()
    {
        imgVw=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.display_Images);


        btnStartStop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause_Resume);
        btnChapter=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChapter);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the button when the sound clip starts and then use the `setOnCompletionListener` method of the `MediaPlayer` class ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29)) to register a handler that will enable the button again. Hope that helps:)

Comment: Button is enable but My activity is finish i don't want to finish my activity .

Comment: @tazeen Are you calling somewhere in your code `finih()`? Also, the code you have provided is quite problematic. Search the internet for any tutorial using the `MediaPlayer`, such as this (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/).

Comment: Yes i have used finish method but now i have removed and demo is run properly.Thanks for the answering.